# querying metadata (GDC Data Portal) in python3

Tags: python

I am trying to query metadata from the Genomic Data Commons (GDC) Data Portal and used the sample code from its website:

```
import requests
import json

cases_endpt = 'https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/cases'

# The 'fields' parameter is passed as a comma-separated string of single names.
fields = ["submitter_id",
          "case_id",
          "primary_site",
          "disease_type",
          "diagnoses.vital_status"
         ]

fields = ','.join(fields)

params = {"fields": fields,
          "format": "TSV",
          "size": "100"
         }

response = requests.get(cases_endpt, params = params)

print(response.content)
```

However, I am not getting a tsv file in return. I am ultimately getting an FPKM instead. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str()` to convert bytes to strings and `print()` with the proper separator.

```
import requests
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

cases_endpt = 'https://api.gdc.cancer.gov/cases'

fields = ["submitter_id",
          "case_id",
          "primary_site",
          "disease_type",
          "diagnoses.vital_status"
          ]

fields = ','.join(fields)

params = {"fields": fields,
          "format": "TSV",
          "size": "100"
          }

response = requests.get(cases_endpt, params=params)

content = str(response.content, 'utf-8')

print(content, sep='\t', end='\r')
```

If you want to convert to a data frame you can use `StringIO()` to load a data frame from an input string directly to a pandas data frame.

```
data = StringIO(content)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\t')
```

The output:

|  | case_id | disease_type | id | primary_site | submitter_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 375436b3-66ac-4d5e-b495-18a96d812a69 | Adenomas and Adenocarcinomas | 375436b3-66ac-4d5e-b495-18a96d812a69 | Rectum | TCGA-F5-6810 |
| 1 | 38f93ca8-4971-4932-b592-0a17eaece2ad | Ductal and Lobular Neoplasms | 38f93ca8-4971-4932-b592-0a17eaece2ad | Pancreas | C3L-02115 |
| 2 | 5ea1361a-050d-4fa0-be59-b530c456b6e3 | Ductal and Lobular Neoplasms | 5ea1361a-050d-4fa0-be59-b530c456b6e3 | Pancreas | C3L-00928 |
| 3 | 690378f3-e38a-4b25-8489-05a3b4bd40b6 | Adenomas and Adenocarcinomas | 690378f3-e38a-4b25-8489-05a3b4bd40b6 | Kidney | C3N-01175 |
| 4 | 6b4f086e-4ef9-4f30-874e-8a155b2e3bab | Squamous Cell Neoplasms | 6b4f086e-4ef9-4f30-874e-8a155b2e3bab | Other and ill-defined sites | C3N-04276 |